# Submit data to database without form

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, mongodb

My question is for example  created a `<input type="text" class="some-class-here" value >`without the form tag and then when the value is input.

By using the `"keypress"` function in jquery, saving the value to a `var`.

for example, I have several of the `input` tags, and when the user press on "next" button, it will input the value in the `var` and create a `user/signup` for that user, without having the use a signup form.

I don't think I explain it clearly. but hope you can get the idea what I would like to express.

I'm using node.js and mongodb

Comment: By using AJAX. It's a browser technique that allows you to send/receive data from/to a server by using JS. Noawadays this is implemented as the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in most modern browsers.

Comment: if you have your api working with nodejs for taking input, then you can send the html input box data by using ajax using onclick of button

Comment: Any tutorial i can find online or source to learn using then fetch api or make my own?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you are using jquery(since you have added tag) and you have some input fields and there is Save button

On click you get all those input values, form a JSON and send it by ajax Call

```
function saveDetail(){

    var name = $("#inputFirstname").val();
    var from = $("#sourceZone1").val();
    var to = $("#destinationZone1").val();
    var source = $("#sourceaddress").val();
    var destination = $("#destinationaddress").val();
    var srcTranslationType = $("#combo").val();
    var srcTranStaticIpTransAddr = $("#inputAddressLine5").val();

    var jsonToSend = {
        name: name,
        from: from,
        to: to,
        source: source,
        destination: destination,
        srcTranslationType: srcTranslationType,
        srcTranStaticIpTransAddr: srcTranStaticIpTransAddr

    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "../policy/nat?id=" + id,
        data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo),
        success: function(data) {
        alert("Successfully added information");

        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error while Adding Detail...");
        }
    });

}
```

click event

```
$("#btnSaveDetail").click(function(){ 
    saveDetail();

});
```

Comment: yes i am using jquery. but inside the $.ajax what is the url refer to??????

Comment: thats the API where you will send your Data to backend.  .  Same as in case of Form submit you will use a URL to Submit to .from action attr ..  <form action="/save/detail method="post">

Comment: Thank you so much. So the url is the action attr in the form tag right?